# Comparing functions using asymptotic notations

Tags: asymptotics

I am learning algorithmic analysis and I want to know how to compare functions...I am trying to apply the definitions of Big Oh, Omega and theta yet unable to find the correct answer.

For example, how to know if $f(n) = 100n^{5.001} + n^5\log(n)^{10}$ is

(a) $O(n^{10})?$

(b) $\Theta(n^5\log(n))?$

(c) $\Theta(n^{5.001}\log(n))?$

(d) $\Omega(n^{5.001} + n^5\log(n))?$

(e) $\Omega(\sqrt n)?$

(f) $o(n^{5.1})?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\begin{cases}\infty,&g(n)\in o(f(n))\\c\ne0,&g(n)\in\Theta(f(n))\\0,&g(n)\in\omega(f(n))\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, It's the same for f(n) ∈ Ωg(n), f(n) ∈ Θ g(n), and f(n) ∈ O g(n), respectively based on the order of your answer.

Comment: @Blackmist You are welcome. Just remember that what I have written are **if and only if** conditions i.e. $\lim\to\infty\iff g(n)\in o(f(n))$. While $g(n)\in o(f(n))\implies g(n)\in O(f(n))$, the reverse implication is not true when $g(n)\in\Theta(f(n))$ and you are all good ^_^

Comment: ohh okay, thank you for the clarification. Already knowing how to correctly solve them now :')